# Waiting for mysql database query complete before proceeding

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm having an issue where I want to wait for a async database query and it's operations before I continue.

I could of course put operations inside a pyramid, but it won't be cool on the long run, because I will have to duplicate code some of the times.

Here is my example (that will of course not work currently, because of async on database queries):

```
var level = 5;
var difficulty = 30; //example
let randomDecider = Math.floor(Math.random()*(50+level)+1);
if (difficulty < randomDecider) {
  var type;
  var name;
  var heroid = "";
  dbconn.query("SELECT * FROM owned_heroes WHERE user = ? AND equipped = 1", [req.session.login], function(err, result, fields) {
    heroid = result[0].heroid;
  });
  if (randomDecider > 50) {
    type = "skill";
    var ownedSkills = [];
    var skillsKeys = Object.keys(Skill);
    dbconn.query("SELECT * FROM owned_skills WHERE user = ? AND heroid = ? AND equipped = 1", [req.session.login, heroid], function(err, result, fields) {
      for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        ownedSkills.push(result[i].name);
      }
    });
    //Here later I also want to remove ownedSkills from skillsKeys.
    name = skillsKeys[Math.floor(Math.random()*skillsKeys.length)];
  }
  else {
    type = "item";
    var itemsKeys = Object.keys(Item);
    var ownedItems = [];
    dbconn.query("SELECT * FROM owned_items WHERE user = ? AND heroid = ? AND equipped = 1", [req.session.login, heroid], function(err, result, fields) {
      for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        ownedItems.push(result[i].name);
      }
    });
    //Here later I also want to remove ownedItems from itemsKeys.
    name = itemsKeys[Math.floor(Math.random()*itemsKeys.length)];
  }
  //Some other code using the type and name variable.
```

So could someone based on this explain me how would I convert this into something working, like waiting for the actions after queries to complete before going forward.
I tried async/await, but I couldn't figure it out currently.

Also any other suggestions to the code is highly welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: Go take a read on `Promise`s. It can allow you to avoid the callback pyramid hell while solving your problem. You can try wrapping the query function into Promises.

Comment: @ionizer Could you please show me an example on how would you wrap the query functions? Just on one query function and I'll be very grateful.

Comment: You can try this kind of code: `function q(str, params) { return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {dbconn.query(str, params, (err, result, fields) => {if (err) reject(err); resolve(result)})})}`. I have came up with an answer using this if you don't mind to wait a little more.

Comment: @ionizer Yeah sure if you want I can wait for the answer, but I think I know what you mean and will be able to get it to work, but still I'll wait for a neat version. :)

Comment: I've posted an answer, you can pick either approach. What version of Node are you using btw?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have explained in the comments about using `Promise`s. And I assume you're using the `mysql` library for your NodeJS program.

So first, to avoid the pyramid (or callback hell as we usually call it), we can try wrapping the async function into a `Promise` like so:

```
function queryPromise(str, params) { 
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    dbconn.query(str, params, (err, result, fields) => {
      if (err) reject(err); 
      resolve(result);
    })
  })
}
```

Then, I only promisified the important part:

```
var level = 5;
var difficulty = 30; //example
let randomDecider = Math.floor(Math.random() * (50 + level) + 1);
if (difficulty < randomDecider) {
  var type;
  var name;
  var heroid = "";

  queryPromise("SELECT * FROM owned_heroes WHERE user = ? AND equipped = 1", [req.session.login]).then(result => {
    heroid = result[0].heroid;
    if (randomDecider > 50) {
      ........
```

You can use this function for your other queries as well. But wait! Is this not the same as putting it into the pyramid? Well, it is **more or less** the same and is usually the way to do it so your code executes the way we want it to. But now, we can chain the Promise's `.then()`s from the other queries inside and avoid indenting your code even more which result in creating the callback hell. Though, this is not what I like to do as Promise chaining also brings about hell when we're not careful with it.

If you're using Node 8 or above, using `async await` is the best solution. Considering `async await` uses Promises as well, we can do it like this:

```
var level = 5;
var difficulty = 30; //example
let randomDecider = Math.floor(Math.random() * (50 + level) + 1);
if (difficulty < randomDecider) {
  var type;
  var name;
  var heroid = "";

  let heroidQuery = await queryPromise("SELECT * FROM owned_heroes WHERE user = ? AND equipped = 1", [req.session.login]);
  heroid = heroidQuery[0].heroid;

  if (randomDecider > 50) {
      ........
```

Looks much better now, isn't it? As the keyword suggests, `await` makes your code wait for the result to be retrieved from your query. Just don't forget to wrap that whole code into an `async function()` block as `await` is not allowed outside `async` functions.

```
async function myfunc() {
  var level 5;
  ....
```

I suggest looking into libraries such as `mysql2/promise` or even `sequelize` which uses Promises when you're comfortable with Promises (or even better, together with async-await)

I hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: One question, if I put let's say "myfunc()" as async then how do I wait for it's return call, because I'm doing like so:
`var squareweb = myfunc();`
And later using the squareweb variable so myfunc() can't really be async. Will I have to be creating another promise for myfunc() or ?

Comment: `async` functions returns a Promise, and whatever you `return` from inside of them are the same with `resolve()`-ing a promise with data. So you can use `squareweb.then()` or even use `await` again. What is the purpose of `var squareweb` and how will it be used?

Comment: `somefunc(req).then(function(gweb) { squareweb = gweb; /*Some other code*/ }`
Done the job. Big thanks :)